# Setting a new variable in each multiple of 10, with no limit

Tags: php

i'm hoping someone can help with my question.

Let's say I have a quantity which is simply an integer in a variable. I know that if the quantity is below 10, the cost will be 1.50. Between 10-20 the cost would be 1.50 x 2, then between 20-30 the cost would be 1.50 x 3 and so on.

The bit im stuck on is the "and so on". I know how I could code this if I knew there was a limit of let's say 100, however if it can be limitless, how could I code this in an intelligent way to work it out for me?

Sorry for the example-less question. I wouldn't know where to start with this query.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Multiply by `ceil($quantity/10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your steps are in tenfold, you can simply divide your number by 10 to get the amount of 1.5's you'll need to calculate the cost.

Then, we'll use [`ceil()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to round the divison to the next integer. Now, for example, `5/10 = 0,5` results in `return 1.5 * 1;`

Take a look at this example;

```php
<?php

function getCost($n) {
    return 1.5 * ceil($n / 10);
}

var_dump(getCost(5));           float(1.5)
var_dump(getCost(15));          float(3)
var_dump(getCost(25));          float(4.5)
var_dump(getCost(35));          float(6)
var_dump(getCost(100));         float(15)
var_dump(getCost(12345));       float(1852.5)
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLK600L7kkMz9PIT21xDm/uERDJU9ToZpLAQiKUktKi/IUDPVMFbQUklMzc4ByCvoKhgaa1ly1XFxliUXxKaW5BRownaaaQAkMUUPswkbYhY1xGGJggF3cyNgErIPz/38A)